# NodeMCU unable to connect to mobile hotspot when I include codes for reading the temperature sensor

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu, iot, lm35

Good day.

The NodeMCu successfully connected to mobile hotspot when i didn't put any others codes except the Wifibegin etc.

Howveer when I include some codes for temparature sensor, it keeps on connecting whereas the everything else including the SSID, password remain the same.

Below are my codes, I tried many, I mean I tried almost everything possible(that's stated in forums), read forums after forum. Please let me know if I missed something out here.

Thanks!

PS:  i attached my codes here

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WifiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

/* Wi-Fi setting connect to your smartphone Wi-Fi hotspot */
const char *ssid = "Thanks";
const char *password = "​For reading";

/* Variable for taking out LM35 value */
String tempValue;
int analogValue;
int tempPin = A0;
float milliVolts;
float celcius;
/* Variable for sending data to server */
String postData;
int httpCode;
String payload;
void setup(){
//delay(1000);
Serial.begin(115200);
WiFi.begin(ssid,password);
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Connecting");
/* If Wi-Fi hotspot is not found, show ..... in serial monitor */
while(WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED){
delay(500);
Serial.println(".");
}
/* If Wi-Fi hotspot is found, show IP address in serial monitor */
Serial.println("");
Serial.println("Connected to ");
Serial.println(ssid);
Serial.println("IP address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}
void loop(){
/* Getting value from LM35 */
delay(1000);
analogValue = analogRead(tempPin);
milliVolts = (analogValue/1024.0)*3300;
celcius = milliVolts/10;
tempValue = String(celcius);
Serial.println(tempValue);
/* Sending LM35 value to server */
HTTPClient http;
postData = "tempValue=" + tempValue;
http.begin("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx/dbInsert.php");
http.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpCode = http.POST(postData);
payload = http.getString();
Serial.println(httpCode); //Print HTTP return code
Serial.println(payload); //Print request response payload
http.end();
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing from the question. Also, what temperature sensor did you use and what pins did you use to connect your sensor?

Comment: @StarCat Hello. Thanks for replying..Edited. Codes as attached. 3.3V, GND,A0

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the delay - this **STOPS** processing for five seconds, not really what you want in a wifi scenario - some routers might disconnect you in this time if no pingbackis are coming
If you need a 5 second- non blocking break for your routines look at this example 
ArduinoIDE -> examples -> 2 Digital -> blinkwithoutdelay.
For further assistance copy and paste your code in code tags and not as a picture.

Comment: Hello . Thanks for your feedback. I  edited and pasted the code in text form. I tried omitting the delay(5000), but still doesn't work out... I reexamine the codes, and can't see the prob, please let me know you can detect the problem...thank you!!!

Comment: You still have delay in your loop, as long as you use delays debugging is useless /* Getting value from LM35 */
delay(1000); => get rid replace with something if(millis() - startTime < timeToWait)...  >> see blinkwithoutdelay example